Определение грамматической основы (2)
Определите, пожалуйста, грамматическую основу предложения.
Как же я рад тебя видеть!

Как же я рад тебя видеть!

Грамматическая основа предложения: я рад видеть. Я — подлежащее, рад видеть — составное глагольное сказуемое.

Составное глагольное сказуемое (СГС) имеет следующую структуру: краткое прилагательное рад (с нулевой связкой быть)  + инфинитив видеть.
Приинфинитивная часть выражает грамматическое значение 
сказуемого, а также дополнительную характеристику действия — 
указание на его начало, середину или конец (фазисное 
значение) или возможность, ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ, степень обычности 
и другие характеристики, описывающие отношение субъекта 
действия к этому действию (модальное значение).

Литневская, стр. 78

Тебя — прямое дополнение к переходному глаголу видеть (кого/что) тебя (2-е значение в словаре). Сильное управление, обязательное дополнение или придаточное. В состав грамматической основы не входит.

ВИДЕТЬ, вижу, видишь; видимый; -дим, -а, -о; виденный; виден, видена, -дено; нсв. 1. Иметь зрение; обладать каким-л. зрением. Плохо, хорошо в. Совы видят ночью. 2. (св. увидеть). кого-что и с придат. дополнит. Воспринимать зрением. В. горы вдали. Видишь огонёк?

Я рад тебя видеть - грамматическая основа.
(Если убрать "тебя", получится, что "я" радуется обретённой способности видеть.)
